# Why must a process in TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE state that is preempted stay in run queue?

Tags: kernel

I'm totally new to the Linux kernel.

In "Understanding the Linux Kernel", page 279, the author says the following, where `prev` refers to the process that called `schedule()`:

> `schedule()` examines the state of prev. If it is not runnable and it has not been preempted in Kernel Mode (see the section “Returning from Interrupts and Exceptions” in Chapter 4), then it should be removed from the runqueue. However, if it has nonblocked pending signals and its state is TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE, the function sets the process state to TASK_RUNNING and leaves it into the runqueue.

Why must `prev` stay in the run queue instead of going into sleep?

What if `prev` is not runnable and preempted in kernel mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you said above:

> ... if it has nonblocked pending signals and its state is TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE ...

By leaving it in the run queue, it'll give the process an opportunity to handle its pending signals.  A process ought to handle pending signals before it sleeps.

Comment: thanks for your fast response. so when state of a process is set to  TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE and the process is placed in some wait queue , it is also stay in run queue to run once more time to handle its pending signal. but how kernel ensure that the process only handles its pending signals, because the process is not supposed to run before occurrence of the event it waits ?

Comment: You're talking about a call to `schedule()`.  "If it is not runnable..." means the process is not ready to run (maybe it's blocked waiting for something), so normally it would be removed from the run queue.  If there are pending signals, however, the kernel can schedule the process and set the process up to handle the pending signals.